# Oauth2 Resource server overlap Spring Security configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I am trying to configure Spring Security and OAuth2 on java config. I am using Spring Security version 4.0.4.RELEASE and OAuth2 version 2.0.11.RELEASE.

Spring Security config works well. Also I can get an access token with OAuth2 AuthorizationServer, but my ResourceServer does not work correctly. When I set the annotation @EnableResourceServer I can only check my access token and other URLs I cannot open (Security configuration and AuthorizationServer configuration do not work). I see the following error:

```
<oauth>
  <error_description>
     An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
  </error_description>
  <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

If I remove an annotation @EnableResourceServer, my ResourceServer does not check an access token. It just redirects to the authentication page.

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class GlobalSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("permissionEvaluator")
    private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;


    @Bean
    public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
        handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return expressionHandler();
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "clientAuthenticationEntryPoint")
    public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entry = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entry.setRealmName("myapp/client");
        entry.setTypeName("Basic");
        return entry;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("webExpressionHandler")
    private DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler;


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/html/**", "/webapi/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/admin/**", "/**")
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests()

                .expressionHandler(expressionHandler)

                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR')")
                .antMatchers("/1/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR')")
                .antMatchers("/profile**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=1")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login-attempt")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
                .and()

                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")

                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                .and()
                .csrf();
    }
}
```

Oauth config:

```
@Configuration
public class Oauth {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_oauth_server";

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .anonymous().disable()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()

                    .regexMatchers("/api/v0/.*").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
            ;

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private AuthorizationCodeServices verificationCodeService;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("clientDetails")
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("tokenStore")
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Bean(name = "tokenServices")
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            return tokenServices;
        }

        @Bean
        public ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter() throws Exception {
            ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter filter = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(verificationCodeService);
            endpoints.tokenServices(tokenServices());
            endpoints.reuseRefreshTokens(true);
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
            oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
            oauthServer.realm("myapp/client");
            oauthServer.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter());
            oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }
    }
}
```

So, ResourceServer config overlap other configuration. How can I fix it? I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to protect some endpoints with an access token, and other endpoints with normal form login.

Can you try restricting the applicability of your `ResourceServerConfiguration` to apply only to certain endpoints by something like: `http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v0/**"))...`. Do the same for `SecurityConfig` but for the endpoints you want it to take care of.

Comment: Hi @sofiaguyang, thanks for coming with an idea. I've restricted the applicability of the `ResourceServerConfiguration` and the `SecurityConfig`. Now I cannot see an error `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`. But I've lost a login button. I don't understand what the problem in my code.

Comment: The general flow is: if you access an endpoint that is protected via OAuth2, you must provide an access token or you will receive an unauthorized / forbidden response. You get an access token via retrieving an auth code from /oauth/authorize and exchanging the auth code with access token from `/oauth/token`. Initially, when a user accesses `/oauth/authorize`, user is not yet authenticated. But because you must be authenticated to authorize, you will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any ideas about Login button? Or I need to try another way to configure ResourceServer? This is my config: `http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v0/**")).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v0/**").authenticated().antMatchers("/**").denyAll(); `